# Sentence which says for any $x\in\mathbb{N}$ there are only finitely many elements less then itself?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Can you form a sentence in $\mathcal{L}=\{\leq\}$ and structure $\mathcal{N}=\{\mathbb{N},\leq\}$ which states for any $x$ not $0$ there are only finitely many elements, less then or equal to $x$?

The definition of sentence I have is the same as this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(mathematical_logic)) article, so I'm assuming it's a standard definition, that being a well formed formula with no free variables.

I know the definition of a formula does not allow for infinite many terms in a formula. So my assumption is that you cannot form a single sentence which says this. But could you form a countable collection of sentences which would be this property?

Comment: For each $n$, can you write a formula $\varphi_n$ which says "if $x=n$, then there are finitely many elements less than or equal to $x$"? Then the collection of all $\varphi_n$ does what you want ^_^

Comment: I'm not sure if I can since $\mathcal{L}$ doesn't have constants. I would want to write something like $\forall_x((x=n)\rightarrow \exists_{x_0},...,\exists_{x_{n-1}}(x_0\leq x)\wedge...\wedge(x_{n-1}\leq x))$

Comment: Assume you had such a sentence. How could it fail to be tue in $\{\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\},\le\}$?

Comment: Think about how you can write $\varphi_n(x)$ so that *there exist* exactly n many predecessors of $x$, which are all distinct.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor That doesn't work - you wind up wanting an infinite disjunction (inside a universal quantifier), whereas an infinite set of first-order sentences would correspond to an infinite *conjunction*. (See my answer.)

Comment: Also, you're right in thinking that no one formula will do the trick - consider $\mathbb{N} \cup \mathbb{Z}$ where we regard each element of $\mathbb{Z}$ as being bigger than every element of $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Noah Schweber, OP asks at the end of their question if a countable family will do

Comment: @HallaSurvivor My point is that it **won't** do: countable families correspond to infinite *conjunctions*, and here we want an infinite *disjunction*. Precisely: there is no set $\Gamma$ (countable or not) of first-order sentences such that $\mathcal{M}\models\Gamma$ iff $\mathcal{M}$ has the finite predecessor property.

Comment: Woops. Good catch. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you cannot do this**.

(And countability doesn't come into play: there is no set $\Gamma$ of first-order sentences such that $\Gamma$ is true in exactly those structures with the countable predecessor property. Now in fact in our case since the language is finite *all* sets of sentences in the language are countable a priori, but it's still worth observing that the following argument style is quite "coarse.")

---

First, let's see why it's fairly implausible.

The natural way to say "every element has only finitely many predecessors" uses an infinite *disjunction* inside a universal quantifier: $$\forall x[\bigvee_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\exists y_1,...,y_n\forall z(z\le x\rightarrow z=y_1\vee ...\vee z=y_n)].$$

Now, if that "$\bigvee$" were a "$\bigwedge$" we could turn this into a countably infinite conjunction of first-order sentences since $$\forall x\bigwedge_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\psi_n(x)\mbox{ is equivalent to }\bigwedge_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\forall x\psi_n(x).$$ But that trick doesn't work here. First of all, "$\forall$" and "$\bigvee$" don't commute; but even if they did, the "$\bigvee$" is fatal since it makes us want an infinite *disjunction* and a countable set of sentences corresponds to an infinite *conjunction*.

---

Of course, the above doesn't prove that you can't do this; it's merely a heuristic argument.

To prove that a property is not first-order expressible, there are two main method: **compactness** and **downward Lowenheim-Skolem** (upward Lowenheim-Skolem is a corollary of compactness). The following is a decent heuristic (but as always don't push it too far): we choose which one to apply based on whether the "bad model" we want to show exists is bad because it's *too big* (in which case we use compactness) or *too small* (in which case we use DLS).

In this case, we want to show that if $\varphi$ is a sentence true in every structure where each element has only finitely many predecessors then it "overspills" - that is, there is some structure where some element *doesn't* have only finitely many predecessors but where $\varphi$ still holds. This tells us that we want to apply **compactness**.

So: do you see how to use compactness to show that if $\varphi$ is true in every structure with the finite predecessor property, it's also true in some structure without the finite predecessor property? *(HINT: it's going to look almost identical to the proof that there's no first-order sentence true in exactly the finite structures. Remember, the key trick there was **expanding the langauge** ...)*

Comment: Incidentally, this may make you start thinking of some kind of **hierarchy**: e.g. first-order sentences are at level one, infinite conjunctions of first-order sentences are at level two, infinite conjunctions of infinite disjunctions of first-order sentences are at level three, and so forth. This leads to [infinitary logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/). There it *is* quite important to pay attention to the sizes of the infinite conjunctions/disjunctions; the best situation is indeed when we limit them to be countable.